# Javascript replace not replacing case insensitive even with the tag applied

Tags: javascript, replace

I have the following code, in which im trying to replace multiple values, I need it to be case insensitive as the string will be dynamic ...I have the `/gi/` flag on the replace function but it doesn't seem to be working.

If i put the values in the newStr as lowercase, it works perfect though.

```
let newStr = 'Colour and brand';

let mapItemObj = {
    brand: data['Brand'],
    colour: data['Colour']
};

newStr = newStr.replace(/brand|colour/gi, function (matched) {
    return mapItemObj[matched];
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`matched` is actually matching exactly what your input text is, in your case `Brand` and `Colour`, you'll need `mapItemObj[matched.toLowerCase()]` since keys are case sensitive in JS.

Answer (score 0):

Well seeing as the variable data is not defined in the above code, it's hard to tell exactly what you're trying to do, but if you want to replace multiple words in a string with predefined mapped values, then just simply split the string and check is lowerCased values:

```js
let newStr = 'Colour and Brand';
var mapToReplace = {
  colour: "hiThere",
  brand: "WoW HELLO"
}
newStr = newStr.split(" ").map(x =>
  mapToReplace[x.toLowerCase()] || x
).join(" ");

console.log(newStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'Colour and Brand'.replace(/brand|colour/gi,function(a){ console.log(a)}) will output
Colour & Brand
```

so the let mapItemObj[matched] will not be able to match with the keys of mapItemObj which are in lower case, this will work if u change matched to lowerCase

```
let newStr = 'Colour and brand';

let mapItemObj = {
    brand: data['Brand'],
    colour: data['Colour']
};

newStr = newStr.replace(/brand|colour/gi, function (matched) {
    return mapItemObj[matched.toLowerCase()];
});
```